# Are there actually Blades with 3 or 4 crowns?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I've bonded numerous Blades already (I believe it is 60+ cores), and already got several rare (5 crowns) Blades.  Yet, aside of this, I'm getting only common 1-2 crowns Blades (which are one of 4 basic variants with different weapons and elements). Which leads me to question - are there actually any 3-4 crown Blades?

It may be possibly related to fact, that I'm using only common cores, saving rare ones, but still, my 7 rare Blades were obtained exclusively from common cores, so I'm not sure why could you get 5-crown Blade from common core, but not 3 or 4 crown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get those. I believe you get them more commonly if you use rare or legendary core crystals, but don't get a rare blade. See:

[image]
[image]